# Zabbix 5.4: Report manager is disabled

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I just installed Zabbix 5.4 and i want to test 'scheduled reports' but i keep getting:

> ```
> Report manager is disabled.
> ```

Here's the interface:
[image]

Since the feature is new i can't find a solution. so if someone is familiar please help me fix it and enable the report manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable report writer in server config.
In `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf` (assuming you are running Zabbix on a Linux machine) change the value of `StartReportWriters` to at least 1, then restart the server.

#### Edit

You also need to set `WebServiceURL` parameter in `zabbix_server.conf`. The URL should be in format `<host>:<port>/report`. Default port is 10053.

```
WebServiceURL=http://localhost:10053/report
```

`/report` path is mandatory and hardcoded, and so can not be changed.

Next, *Frontend URL* parameter must be set. Go to *Administration → General → Other parameters*, and specify the full URL of the Zabbix web interface in the *Frontend URL* parameter.

[image: Image from official documentation]

More detailed instructions can be found in [official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/install/web_service).

Comment: Thank you it did work but now i get    `The Frontend URL has not been configured`

Comment: I edited and expanded my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: But i've followed all the instruction and i got  ` Cannot connect to web service: couldn't connect to server`

Comment: You probably don't have `zabbix-web-server` installed. It's available in Zabbix [repositories](https://repo.zabbix.com/). You also need to have Google Chrome browser installed.

Comment: Does it work with chromium ? i followed zabbix install  ` apt install zabbix-server-pgsql zabbix-frontend-php php7.4-pgsql zabbix-nginx-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-agent ` i didn't find zabbix-web-server

Comment: I meant `zabbix-web-service`, sorry it's late over here. Install it with `apt install zabbix-web-service`. While it can work with chromium, there is a [known issue](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/known_issues#chromium_for_zabbix_web_service_on_ubuntu_20) (bottom of the page) of it NOT working on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Okay I will check the suggested solution and i will keep you updated. Thank you very much for your effort and support

Comment: it did work after creating manually by creating /var/lib/zabbix as shown bellow
`   mkdir -p /var/lib/zabbix/
    chown zabbix:zabbix /var/lib/zabbix/
    chmod 755 /var/lib/zabbix/` but the repport i got is 404 error